# Easy border for tikz and forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, fbox

Using `\fbox` around `forest` creates unwanted horizontal paddings to my graphs:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[bth]
    \fboxsep = 4pt % Does not matter
    \fbox{\begin{forest}
        [A [B [D [I] [J] [K] ]
              [E [L] [M] ] ]
           [C [F] [G] [H] ] ]
    \end{forest}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Using fbox with forest]

Removing `\fbox` aligns the diagram properly. However, I cannot get TikZ's background library to work with `forest`.

Using

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% ...
\tikzset{every picture/.style={show background rectangle}}
```

fails with the error "Dimension too large".

I now use TikZ nodes to create a frame around the `forest` environment:

```
\begin{forest}
    tikz+={\draw
        (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    },
    [A [B [D [I] [J] [K] ]
          [E [L] [M] ] ]
       [C [F] [G] [H] ] ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: Using tikz nodes to draw a frame]

This works fine, but seems way too complicated and not very clean, especially when a custom inner padding is required (I solved this using `xshift`/`yshift` on the rectangle).

Are there better ways to achieve a frame around **every** TikZ and `forest` image?

**Update: Working solution for all forest environments**

This solution from the comments creates the desired frame for all forest environments:

```
\forestset{default preamble={tikz+={\tikzset{show background rectangle}}}}
```

Of course, `\tikzset{every picture/.style={show background rectangle}}` still results in the above mentioned error, requiring `show background rectangle` being set in every picture.

**Update 2: Bugfixes as of 2019-07-29:**

As mentioned in the comments:

1. the issue preventing tikzset could be fixed with the next release of forest,
2. there is a pull request to remove the leaking space leading to the padding in TikZ/PGF.

Comment: With your third solution you can just use `\forestset{default preamble={tikz+={\tikzset{show background rectangle}}}}` to make every tree boxed. That seems like the simplest solution. BTW, the warning not to use `\fbox` with TikZ is about using `\fbox` inside a TikZ node, not about wrapping a TikZ picture in an `\fbox`.

Comment: The problem is not `\fbox`. Add a `A` just before your `forest` environment and you get an  unwanted horizontal padding...

Comment: The "Dimension too large" error occurs because forest typesets each node separately in a `tikzpicture` environment (to measure it), but defers its positioning (see 106.2.3 Deferred Node Positioning in PGF manual 3.1.3) so that the node's picture is empty. As you can check, an empty `tikzpicture` environment produces the same error. I will address this problem in the next release of `forest` by locally resetting `every picture`, so that it will apply only to the entire tree.

Comment: Horizontal space is due to a leaking space in PGF. See my pull request at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/pull/723

Comment: Merged into master.

Comment: @AlanMunn Is there a temporary workaround for this as the fix still isn't distributed through the usual channels?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to a bug in PGF/TikZ which has now been fixed. The pull request by  Sašo Živanović at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/pull/723 has now been merged into the master as per his comment at [Easy border for tikz and forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501270/easy-border-for-tikz-and-forest#comment1268180_501270).